# Erro de responsividade

Tags: html, css, mobile

Estou acompanhando um material da caelum e estou com dificuldade de fazer um página responsiva.[image: Correto]

Gostaria dela ficar assim, mas ela está aparecendo assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.container{
  width: 96%;
}
header h1{
  text-align: center;
}
header h1 img{
  max-width: 50%;
}
.sacola{
  display: none;
}
.menu-opcoes{
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-opcoes ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sobre a Mirror Fashion</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sobre.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sobre-mobile.css" media="(max-width: 939px)">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="container">
      <h1><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Mirror Fashion"></h1>
      <p class="sacola">Nenhum item na sacola de compras</p>
      <nav class="menu-opcoes">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sua Conta</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lista de Desejos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cartão Fidelidade</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ajuda</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Você queria alinhas a div do conteúdo no centro da página?

Comment: isso, eu criei duas páginas com o mesmo cabeçalho, na outra página deu certo, mas nessa não, quando vou inspecionar no google chrome, não sei como explicar esta área branca

Comment: Tem como você editar a pergunta e colocar seu código html e css?

Comment: Ve se você colocar isso aqui resolve:
.container{
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: Infelizmente não

Comment: Que pena, porém mantenha o _margin: 0 auto;_ pois ele é responsável por deixar o conteúdo no centro da página. Adicione o seguinte css e veja se resolve: html, body { width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Comment: o reset poderia influenciar? testei esta sua última dica e não deu certo

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer com reset. Se você se refere a limpar algum float, tenta fazer assim: .container:after { clear: both;  }

Comment: neste projeto criei dois arquivos html e os dois tem o mesmo cabeçalho, no arquivo index.html a resposividade do cabeçalho funcionou, já na outra página não, está com esse problema, a única diferençano cabeçalho deste dois arquivos é o reset que coloquei no arquivo index

Comment: Infelizmente acho que só executando o seu projeto aqui na minha maquina eu conseguiria identificar o problema. Se não for problema pra você, manda seu projeto pra mim por e-mail e eu analiso melhor, caso contrário, se tiver como colocar ele no ar por e me passar o link, também da pra eu ver.

Comment: posso mandar o link do github? algum problema?

Comment: pode sim, sem problemas

Comment: https://github.com/Pakato14/projetoweb

Comment: Blz, vou dar uma olhada e te falo

Comment: Certo! ficarei no aguardo

Comment: Qual é a página que está com problema mesmo?

Comment: sobre.html, consegue visualizar quando inspeciona no modo mobile

Comment: Cara respondi aqui embaixo, espero que você entenda. Caso ajudar, da um upvote aí na resposta pra ajudar. Valeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá ... depois de ver seu código encontrei alguns problemas.

No html, exite a meta tag ***viewport***, essa meta tag serve para o browser entender qual resolução ele deve levar em consideração dependendo do dispositivo. Eu aconselho colocar assim:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Porém seria bom dar uma olhada [neste artigo](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) para entender melhor sobre isso.

Segundo problema. Você está setando tamanhos fixos no css em alguns elementos, como por exemplo ***.corpo*** e ***.container*** que estão com 940px, ou  **#centro-distribuicao*** que está com 550px.

Sendo assim, ou você teria que utilizar ***css media queries*** para alterar esses tamanhos de acordo com a resolução ([veja este link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)) ou colocar o tamanho destes elementos em percentual para que eles se ajustem conforme diminuir a página.

Pra resumir, seu problema era o ***viewport*** junto com um elemento que etava com um tamanho muito grande, ou seja. Este elemento fazia a página ficar grande, porém não o topo que estava com percentual setado. Ele se encaixava ao viewport corretamente, já o restante não.

Bom, espero que tenha entendido.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!!!! O link sobre o css media queries não abriu, mas resolveu o problema aqui a sua dica.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Editei o link, mas se procurar sobre media queries que vc vai achar bastante coisa. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

No seu `CSS` coloque o estilo para sua tag:

```
ul{
   margin:0; 
   padding:0;
}
```

Isso define a margem externa e interna para zero e deve eliminar os espaços em branco.

Não testei mas deve resolver.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não deu certo